# Woocommerce Order Details Shortcode

Tags: woocommerce

Iam trying to create a custom thank you page for my product. After payment it has to redirect and show the Thank you for payment text with the Order details (Order Number, Product etc). I tried to use this shortcode to get the order details. But its not working

```
   [woocommerce_orders]
```

Can anyone pls help me to get the right shortcode to show the order informations on the payment confirmation page. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is not any shortcode for that… Instead of creating a 2nd custom thankyou page, you should better change existing one with if/else statements (on the main template and on sub templates too) to alter it as you want for your particular case.